# Should one literally think "I am breathing in long, I am breathing out long."

Tags: anapanasati

Per the teachings of the Anapanasati Sutta, should one literally think about what they are doing, or focus on the breath itself?

Meaning, should I think "I am breathing in long," or should I focus on the action of my breath being long?

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary to think: "*I am*". The mind should know the action of the breath being long or being short. Also, there is really no need to "*focus*". When the mind is quiet & silent, the mind will know the breathing. Be as silent, still, upright, awake & alert as possible.

Note: At the highest level of practise, the Buddha taught to reflect:

> *Monks, whatever form, past, future or present, internal or external, coarse or fine, low or lofty, far or near, all that form must be
>   regarded with proper wisdom, according to reality, thus: 'This is not
>   mine, **this I am not**, this is not my self.'*
>
> [*SN 22.59*](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.mend.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it helps you to be in the *moment*, then by all means do it.

Remember that breathing is just our anchor to the *moment*, to the *now*.

Let go of everything else. You can even let go of this idea. As long as the breath brings you to the present moment, it is doing its job.